# List of radiobuttons in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form that give name and gender of users as a input data.In fact, this form of input is taken name with gender. My bean code is:

```
public class Info{
  private List<String> names;
  private List<Gender> genders;
}

public enum Gender{
 Male,
 Fmale,
 Unknone;
 //
}
```

now i want to form like this

```
  <c:forEach begin="0" end="10" varStatus="s">
    <tr>
      <td> <form:input path="names[${s.index}]" /> </td>
      <td><form:radiobutton path="genders" value="<%=Gender.Male%>"></td> 
      <td><form:radiobutton path="genders" value="<%=Gender.Fmale%>"></td> 
      <td><form:radiobutton path="genders" value="<%=Gender.Unknone%>"></td> 
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

but when run project catch this exception

```
   org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="10" varStatus="s">
<tr>
  <td> <form:input path="names[${s.index}]" /> </td>
  <td><form:radiobutton path="sexes[${s.index}]" value="<%=Sex.Male%>"></td> 
  <td><form:radiobutton path="sexes[${s.index}]" value="<%=Sex.Fmale%>"></td> 
  <td><form:radiobutton path="sexes[${s.index}]" value="<%=Sex.Unknone%>"></td> 
</tr>
```